# Unable to serve Cesium Terrain files

Tags: geoserver, javascript, 3d, terrain, cesium

I am trying to generate 3d Terrain.
I am serving the terrain files at localhost:8081

Here is the Cesium Code

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    terrainProvider : new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : 'localhost:8081'
    })
});
```

I get the following error:

> An error occurred in "CesiumTerrainProvider": An error occurred while accessing localhost:8081/layer.json.

This is my layer.json file and i have given appropriate access permissions:

```
{
  "tilejson": "2.1.0",
  "format": "heightmap-1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scheme": "tms",
  "tiles": ["{z}/{x}/{y}.terrain?v={version}"]
}
```

Comment: If you try directly visiting `localhost:8081/layer.json` in a browser, does it show your json file?

Comment: Yes it shows the file. That's why I can't figure out what to do. I have disabled security settings of Firefox too in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `http://` on the front of the URL:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    terrainProvider : new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : 'http://localhost:8081'
    })
});
```

Also, if Cesium itself is not served from port 8081 locally, then you will need to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) on your 8081 server, to work around the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a folder in webApps where you had placed your terrain files. By saying this 'localhost:8081' you mean to say all my files are placed in WebApps root folder.

Create a folder place all terrain files in it, append folder name to after port with slash and give it a shot.

Comment: I tried putting all the files in a folder. it still fails. the folder containing all the terrain files was built using ctb. I doubt that is the issue