# Cannot access Terrain Server for Cesium

Tags: terrain, cesium

I'm trying to follow a series of tutorials:

[visualizing-terrains-with-cesium-ii](https://bertt.wordpress.com/2018/11/26/visualizing-terrains-with-cesium-ii/)

[visualizing-terrains-with-cesium](https://bertt.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/visualizing-terrains-with-cesium/)

Some other useful posts here:

[Unable to serve Cesium Terrain files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/unable-to-serve-cesium-terrain-files)

[error-in-loading-terrain-files-terrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387262/error-in-loading-terrain-files-terrain)

Basically, I want to use my own terrain files within Cesium.

I'm stack in configuring the terrain server aspect,

I have a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) server running Cesium Apps in port 8080:
http://localhost:8080/Apps/own_terrain.html

Path for the html file is:

```
C:/Users/username/Downloads/software/Cesium-1.53/Apps/own_terrain.html
```

The terrain files have been generated by using: [cesium-terrain-builder-docker](https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker)

Then, I want to run my terrain tiles using [cesium-terrain-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/geodata/cesium-terrain-server/) in docker.

This is how I built it:

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 -v C:/Users/username/Downloads/software/Cesium-1.53/Apps/terrain:/data/tilesets/terrain \
geodata/cesium-terrain-server
```

So, Cesium running in 8080 and terrain server in 9000,

However when I try to access the terrain tiles, i.e:

```
http://localhost:9000/tilesets/tiles/0/0/0.terrain
```

Nothing happens, Chrome says:

```
localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

And the same when integrating that into the own_terrain.html:

```
Cesium.js:445 GET http://localhost:9000/tilesets/tiles/layer.json net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Definitely the terrain server is not running. What am I missing in these tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is super old but faced a similar issue.

Turns out, the cesium-terrain-server was listening to Port 8000 inside docker. I verified it by running the image in interactive mode

```
docker run -p 4000:80 --rm -v $PWD:/data/tilesets/terrain -it --env WEB_DIR=/data/tilesets/terrain/ geodata/cesium-terrain-server bash
```

I mapped port 4000 to 80 in the beginning because the documentation instructed me to do so.

Then I ran `cesium-terrain-server` inside the docker and received:

`NOTICE: server listening on port 8000`

So, I just mapped my port 4000 to 8000 and it started serving the terrain tiles.

**After Comment Suggestion**

I was asked to also include how I mapped port 4000 to 8000. Here is how I did it.

```
docker run -p 4000:8000 --rm -v $PWD:/data/tilesets/terrain -it --env WEB_DIR=/data/tilesets/terrain/ geodata/cesium-terrain-server bash
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  How did you map the port from 4000 to 8000?  Can you [edit] your question to include those steps?